# error CS0117: `UnityEditor.PlayerSettings' does not contain a definition for `target IOS Graphics'

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

Im trying to build Google cardboard Demo application on to Android Device(Samsung Gs3), but Im facing a problem. I get an error

> "error CS0117: `UnityEditor.PlayerSettings' does not contain a
>   definition for 'target IOS Graphics'" in CardboardEditor.cs.

Can someone suggest me what mI doing wrong. Help me solve the bug. Im using

> Unity 4.6.2
>
> Cardboard SDK for Unity v0.5
>
> Target Platform : Android

Comment: The error message refers to a file `CardboardEditor.cs`, which is probably a part of the Cardboard SDK. Did you make any changes to that file? If so,  try reverting them. If not, you might be able to fix it, or contact the SDK developer.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
private static void CheckGraphicsAPI()
{
    if (EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTarget == BuildTarget.iPhone
        && !Application.isPlaying
        && Object.FindObjectOfType<Cardboard>() != null
        && PlayerSettings.targetIOSGraphics != TargetIOSGraphics.OpenGLES_2_0
        && PlayerSettings.targetIOSGraphics != TargetIOSGraphics.OpenGLES_3_0)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("iOS Graphics API should be set to OpenGL for best distortion-"
          + "correction performance in Cardboard.");
    }
}
```

With this:

```
private static void CheckGraphicsAPI()
{
    if (EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTarget == BuildTarget.iPhone
        && !Application.isPlaying
        && Object.FindObjectOfType<Cardboard>() != null
        && PlayerSettings.GetGraphicsAPIs(BuildTarget.iPhone).Contains(GraphicsDeviceType.OpenGLES2)
        && PlayerSettings.GetGraphicsAPIs(BuildTarget.iPhone).Contains(GraphicsDeviceType.OpenGLES3))
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("iOS Graphics API should be set to OpenGL for best distortion-"
          + "correction performance in Cardboard.");
    }
}
```

Comment: This again gave me an error CS0117: `UnityEditor.BuildTarget' does not contain a definition for `iOS'. I tried commenting the script and build it, but the app crashed.